# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Unknown Host

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

TFS 2015. I am installing a VSO agent on build server. This agent needs to run under its own AD account. The agent installs fine but it appears offline in TFS. Logs contain the following error:

```
> 16:32:37.077613
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 16:32:37.077613
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException:
> Unknown Host
> 
> 16:32:37.077613    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage
> response)
> 
> 16:32:37.077613    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
> 
> 16:32:37.077613 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
> exception was thrown ---
> 
> 16:32:37.077613    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> 
> 16:32:37.077613    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> 
> 16:32:37.077613    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__76`1.MoveNext()
> 
> 16:32:37.077613 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
> exception was thrown ---
> 
> 16:32:37.077613    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

When I run the agent under my admin account order under network service account then it goes online. Also, in these cases the above exception doesn't appear in logs. I added service account user to service pool's `Agent Pool Administartor` and `Agent pool Service Account` groups but this didn't help. What permissions does it miss?

Comment: Do you run Command Prompt as administrator, then configure agent? Try to configure build agent as interactive mode, then re-configure it as service and check the result.

Comment: Hi, cmd has been run as admin. Also, I tried interactive mode (agent went online) and then again service mode but this put the agent offline as before. One important detail: previously I run another agent (test) on this server. The folder with this test agent is still on file system, but service is stopped and server has been rebooted, so I assume that the old agent doesn't interfere with the one I am trying to configure. To confirm, the agent goes online if run under my admin account or network service account.

Comment: Do you a build agent (test) works fine on the same server? Just the new agent has the issue? Try to download the new agent from TFS, then configure it with a new agent pool and check the result.